# How to increment state count in mapping function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Goal is to increment the count in the mapping function while keeping track of the new value in state. "charlie" isn't updating, even on re-renders of the component, and subsequent runs of mapData. Meanwhile, every re-render/run of mapData continues to print the updated count outside "charlie".
My code looks roughly like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

const mapData = (apiData) => {
  const dataMapped = apiData.map((pic, index) => {
    return (
      setCount(prevState => (prevState+1))
      <div className="charlie">{count}</div> 
    )
  })
  setData(prevState => ([...prevState, ...dataMapped]))
}

return {
  <div>
    <div>{count}</div> {/* shows updated count every render */}
    <div>{data}</div>  {/* shows 0 every render*/}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: this code has a run time error (you must return a single react node from the functional component), you should provide a producible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, you should read about "rules of hooks" you can't run it inside a loop

Comment: @DennisVash mapping function relies on some api data. Just runs over 20 data objects from an api.

Comment: ["Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) please read the docs

Comment: Why can't you just use "length" on apiData? It seems you are using final apiData response, not a chunk. I mean you can move this: `setCount(prevState => (prevState+1))` out of the loop, and make it `setCount(prevState => (prevState+apiData.length))`

Comment: @Animus No, the final count of the api data isn't what I'm after. I'm trying to print a count for every object I receive from the api data, including on subsequent runs, while remembering how much data I've already run through.

Comment: @RobertC got it, but you will call the mapData for every chunk. This way you will add the length of chunk at once, instead of iterating.

Comment: @Animus iterating is what I'm after. I want each object on the webpage to show its number. So if I map over the data 152 times the 152nd object on the webpage shows its 152. I could put every object into an array then index them but I'd rather not introduce that code.

Comment: @RobertC Yes, but look, for every chunk you add length of the chunk to count, and then, inside the loop you add index to the count. This is what I mean. `setCount(prevState => (prevState+apiData.length))` outside the loop, and `{count + index}` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the second time in two days that I am seeing someone doing this. You need to separate your update logic from your render logic. I would strongly recommend storing JSX inside state unless it is some extremely rare scenario. I am going to comment on your code down below with all the mistakes:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

const mapData = (apiData) => {
  const dataMapped = apiData.map((pic, index) => {
    return (
      // three things here:
      // 1. Never set state from inside a loop because it is going to break the order of hook calls
      // 2. Never try to update state during rendering (only do this if you are trying to replicate getDerivedStateFromProps in classes). Add it to useEffect.
      // 3. You do not need to calculate the count like this. You can just use index of the array to find the count.
      setCount(prevState => (prevState+1))
      <div className="charlie">{count}</div> 
    )
  })
  // Do not store React elements inside state
  setData(prevState => ([...prevState, ...dataMapped]))
}

// this where all your rendering should happen
return {
  <div>
    <div>{count}</div> {/* shows updated count every render */}
    <div>{data}</div>  {/* shows 0 every render*/}
  </div>
}
```

This would be a way I would go about doing what you are doing:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const populateData = (apiData) => {
  setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...apiData]); // just in case I need the internals of the array. You can also map the array here to only store the counts
  // if you do not need api data, you can just retrieve the keys, which are the indices of the array
  // setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...apiData.keys()]);
}

return (
  <div>
    <div>{data.length}</div> {/* we already know count from array length */}
    <div>{data.map((item, idx) => (
      <div className="charlie">{idx + 1}</div> {/* render index to get count */}
    ))}</div> 
  </div>
);
```

Comment: So...here's the problem with that approach. I don't need the total length of the array. What I need is the count of each object INSIDE the "charlie" div. In my actual code my mapping function transforms the api data into JSX then stores it in state. Inside one of the divs ("charlie") is a number that should correspond to where the current obj is in the final array,  because it prints it to the user. So obj 50 shows "50" on the webpage inside that HTML.

Comment: This code actually does the count for you because logically the item at position 50 is going to have index 49 (zero-indexed). Because the array is not being sorted, you are actually going to get the count of each object based on array position. However, even if you want to count the counts manually, you still shouldn't use state for that. Just create a variable and assign the values to it properly. Looking at your code again, you are setting the count and concatenating the arrays; so, you are going to have the same count as the concatenated array's length.

Comment: Yes, that's right. An index can be used to update charlie based on the array length. I mentioned not wanting to do that in another comment since it means I have to move a lot of code around, but seems like maybe there isn't a better option.

Comment: The issue that you have stems from the fact that your render and update logics are mixed together. You are trying to an map array into React elements in update and do state updates during rendering. You are not properly separating concerns, which is going to hurt you in the long run. Also, "charlie" divs being in the middle of 30 lines of code should not be a problem. You can create another component and render it with some props. For example, you can render `<CharlieContainer data={apiData} />` that encapsulated the necessary logic to count and render the elements.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, your code doesn't compile

I am assuming that what you are trying to do is to keep track of the amount of data rendered

in that case, you can add the length of the API results to the count

```
const mapData = (apiData) => {
  const dataMapped = apiData.map((pic, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="charlie">{count}</div> 
    )
  })
  setCount(count + dataMapped.length);
  setData(prevState => ([...prevState, ...dataMapped]))
}
```

Comment: This code would update count in chunks of 20 (number of objects I map over from the api). What I'm trying to do is get "charlie" to update for each object I get from the api. So the count would update 1, 2,3 etc to 20.

Comment: Each api request get you a chunk of 20 either way.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this is what you are after, and it allows to avoid `setState` inside the loop:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

const mapData = (apiData) => {
  const dataMapped = apiData.map((pic, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="charlie">{count + index}</div> 
    )
  })
  setCount(prevState => (prevState + apiData.length))
  setData(prevState => ([...prevState, ...dataMapped]))
}

return {
  <div>
    <div>{count}</div> {/* shows updated count every render */}
    <div>{data}</div>  {/* shows 0 every render*/}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: This runs into the same problem as before. {count} doesn't get updated in the mapping function at all. So when I run this code it counts to 20 from 0 each time the code is run. i.e. doesn't remember last amount since count isn't recognized in mapping statement.